# Batch Kronecker product of tensors

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, kronecker-product

I have two tensors that are batches of matrices:

```
x = torch.randn(100,10,10) 
y = torch.randn(100,2,2)
```

I want to parallelize the kronecker on each matrix, not doing the kronecker product of the tensors.  `torch.kron(x,y)` gives me a tensor of size `(10000, 60,60)`, but I want a shape out of size `(100, 60, 60)` that computes the kronecker product for each matrix. Is there any way to do so ?

Something like `torch.kron(x,y, start_dim = 1)` is what I tried but it does not seem to be implemented. (I want to do this in torch for R but something that works in python would already be okay)

Thanks